# While iterating the array, the records are not completely displaying in react hooks page

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

While iterating using `map` function in `react-hooks`, array data is not properly displaying in the page, I could see the array has got 3 records, but while iterating it is displaying only two records and that too same image got displayed twice. Could someone please help me to identify the issue here ?
I can see a warning error logged in console:
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
const [dailyStatusPlayers, setDailyStatusPlayers] = useState([]);
const isMounted = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      isMounted.current = true;
      return () => isMounted.current = false;
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/availability');
            if (isMounted.current) {
               setDailyStatusPlayers(res.data.dailyStatus);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);

   return (
        <div className="availability_wrapper">
         <h4>In: <span className="displayInCount">20</span></h4>
            <div className="wrap">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="dailystatus_section">
                        <span className="playerdailyrecord">
                             <h4>Player Daily Status:</h4>
                            <div className="row">
                                {
                                dailyStatusPlayers.map(([{id, photo, position, dailystatus}]) =>(
                                <div key={id} className="playerdailyrecord_main">
                                <span className="dailstatus_playerphoto"><img className="dailstatus_playerImage" key={photo} src={photo}></img></span>
                                <span className="dailstatus" key={dailystatus}>{dailystatus}</span>
                                <span className="dailstatus_playerposition" key={position}>{position}</span>
                                </div>
                                ))        
                                }
                            </div>
                            <button className="OverlayDailyStatus" onClick={displayAvailabilityStatus}>Enter</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <DailyStatusDialog
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              open={deleteDialog}
              onClose={() => setDeleteDialog(false)}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

```
const Availability = () =>{
  
    const [team1, setTeam1] = useState([]);
    const [team2, setTeam2] = useState([]);
    const [deleteDialog, setDeleteDialog] = useState(false);
    const [playerId, setPlayerId] = useState("");
    const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('');
    const loginUserEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
    const [dailyStatusPlayers, setDailyStatusPlayers] = useState([]);
    const [teamData, setTeamData] = useState([]);
    //const [dailyinput, setDailyInput] = useState('');
    const [inCount, setInCount] = useState("");
    const isMounted = useRef(false);
    const c_day = moment().format('dddd');
    const c_date = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

    useEffect(() => {
      isMounted.current = true;
      return () => isMounted.current = false;
    }, []);

    const displayAvailabilityStatus = () =>{
       setDeleteDialog(true);
    }
     
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/availability');
            if (isMounted.current) {
               setDailyStatusPlayers(res.data.dailyStatus[0]);
               //setTeamData(res.data.dailyStatus[0]);
               console.log("Complete array:"+res.data.dailyStatus[0]);
               
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);


      let i = 0;
      const tempTeam1 = [];
      const tempTeam2 = [];
      while(teamData.length > 0) {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * teamData.length);
        i%2 === 0 ? tempTeam1.push(teamData[random]) : tempTeam2.push(teamData[random]);
        teamData.splice(random, 1);
        i++;
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
      setTeam1(tempTeam1);
      setTeam2(tempTeam2);
      },[]);

   
    const onSubmit = (dailyinput) =>{
        console.log("Here Daily:"+ dailyinput);
        const dailyStatus = async () => {
            try {
                const params = {
                    email: loginUserEmail,
                };
              const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/availability', { dailystatus: dailyinput }, {params} );
              console.log("Dailystatus update" + res.data.success);
              if (res.data.success) {
                setDeleteDialog(false);
              }
              else {
                console.log(res.data.message);
                setHelperText(res.data.message);
              }
            } catch (e) {
              setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
            }
          }
          dailyStatus();
    }

    return (
        <div className="availability_wrapper">
          <div className="displayCurrentDate">
            <b>{c_day}</b>, {c_date}
          </div>
         <h4>In: <span className="displayInCount">20</span></h4>
            <div className="wrap">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="dailystatus_section">
                        <span className="playerdailyrecord">
                             <h4>Player Daily Status:</h4>
                            <div className="row">
                                {
                                dailyStatusPlayers.map(({id, photo, position, dailystatus}) =>(
                                <div key={id} className="playerdailyrecord_main">
                                <span className="dailstatus_playerphoto"><img className="dailstatus_playerImage" key={photo} src={photo}></img></span>
                                <span className="dailstatus" key={dailystatus}>{dailystatus}</span>
                                <span className="dailstatus_playerposition" key={position}>{position}</span>
                                </div>
                                ))        
                                }
                            </div>
                            <button className="OverlayDailyStatus" onClick={displayAvailabilityStatus}>Enter</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="playerdistribution_section">
                            <h4>Team Selection</h4>
                            <div className="wrap">
                                    <div className="left_col">
                                        {
                                        team1.map(({id, name, image}) =>(
                                        <div>
                                             <span key={name}>{name}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        ))
                                      }
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="right_col">
                                        {
                                        team2.map(({id, name, image})=>(
                                          <div>
                                          <span key={name}>{name}</span>
                                          </div>
                                        ))
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="weeklycount_graph_section">
                                <span className="avail_newImageback">
                                  <img className="avail_newsImagesection" src="images/greenplayer.png"></img>         
                              </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <DailyStatusDialog
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              open={deleteDialog}
              onClose={() => setDeleteDialog(false)}
            />
        </div>
    );

}
export default Availability;
```

Comment: I was able to get it to render three items. Check out this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-shockley-ehhfl?file=/src/App.js) and let me know if that solves it. Issue was there was an error with the syntax in the `dailyStatusPlayers.map` function. Also, thanks for another problem :)

Comment: @itsanewabstract. Sorry, I have tried that earlier, the problem is that it is coming as 2D array ( same data in two diff arrays )from server side.I am getting the data using JOIN from table using following query `const dailyStatus = await sequelize.query("SELECT user.id, user.photo, user.position, availability.dailystatus FROM user INNER JOIN availability ON user.id = availability.id", null, { raw: true});` You can see that in screenshot.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of duplicate array from server side if possible...

Comment: Ah, I see. That does sound like a server side issue then. If you can't get rid of the duplicate on the server, could you possibly just use the first index of the wrapping array and ignore the second?

Comment: This doesn't work in server side `const dailyStatus = await sequelize.query("SELECT user.id, user.photo, user.position, availability.dailystatus FROM user INNER JOIN availability ON user.id = availability.id", null, { raw: true});
    let finalStatus = dailyStatus.map(JSON.stringify);`

Comment: How to us  `first index of the wrapping array` and ignore the second?

Comment: Look at this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-bash-45vic?file=/src/App.js). I changed the `mockAxios` function to return a duplicate array, and then `setDailyStatusPlayers(res.data.dailyStatus[0])` in the `useEffect`

Comment: Thank you  that is working, please update your answer

Comment: I have send an email, could you check and reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the array passed in from the server is being duplicated. Until the code on the server is fixed, you can simply pass in the first value of the array by calling `setDailyStatusPlayers(res.data.dailyStatus[0])` inside of the second `useEffect`.

Should also change `dailyStatusPlayers.map(([{id, photo, position, dailystatus}])` to remove the wrapping array. So it should become `dailyStatusPlayers.map(({id, photo, position, dailystatus})`.

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-bash-45vic?file=/src/App.js) with a working example.

Comment: Appreciate you help, upvoted and accepted ! Can i ask one more question here, if I need to pass `res.data.dailyStatus[0]` to another `const [teamData, setTeamData] = useState([]); setTeamData(res.data.dailyStatus[0]); `

Comment: So that I need to use `teamData` to perform some other action would...

Comment: You could potentially do that, I would test it of course. But if you have already passed `res.data.dailyStatus[0]` into the `dailyStatusPlayers` state, then you could also try `setTeamData(dailyStatusPlayers)`. Although since you already have it saved in state I think this would be redundant

Comment: But the problem here ...`if (isMounted.current) {
               setDailyStatusPlayers(res.data.dailyStatus[0]);
               setTeamData(res.data.dailyStatus[0]);
               console.log("Complete array:"+res.data.dailyStatus[0]);
            }`

Comment: Once I set that in setTeamData() the data is not displaying for `dailyStatusPlayers` the  one we solved just now..

Comment: I don't think the `res` object is available inside of the `useEffect` that checks for `isMounted.current` - unless you've added another API call there as well. If so, feel free to fork the Codesandbox I made and provide the link with the new code

Comment: I have added the whole code towards the end of question, at the moment this line is commented  ..`//setTeamData(res.data.dailyStatus[0]);` as soon as if we enable this one..no data is being displayed, i mean the one `dailyStatusPlayers ` which we solved too is not displaying the data..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-sutherland-rmmuq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Seems to be working for me on [my end](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-currying-3nsrr?file=/src/App.js). I included two `pre` tags in the JSX that render the data found in both `dailyStatusPlayers` and `teamData`. The previous data still displays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216686/discussion-between-soccerway-and-itsanewabstract).

Answer (score 1):

From the image provided, I can see the `res.data` is an array (outer array) which has 2 identical item (inner array which has 3 items with `id` and `photo`) .

`dailyStatusPlayers.map(([{id, photo, position, dailystatus}])` is go through outer array => It will render 2 times (outer array), each time `[{id, photo, position, dailystatus}]` will destructure and get first item of inner array ==> you will render 2 times of item id 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2D array, you are iterating over the root array, then selecting the first object in each sub-array.

What is the first object in the first element in the array you are showing? Does it has the id of 1?

Edit: We can now see that both first objects on the sub-arrays have the same key. This is the source of the error.

Comment: I have udpated my question with screenshot of array, yes the first array has id key and value

Comment: So both objects have 1 as key, that's what causes the error.